# How to select same value(string) from two tables

Tags: sql

```
Table_1                             Table_2

name=john                           name=john
age=15                              age=18
```

My goal is to select john, because it is the same name.

Now my idea is:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table_1,Table_2 WHERE (name=name).
```

Comment: google and learn about `join`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into right direction. Is there a better way to do it? I mean different, without join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inner join to merge the two tables where the key you specified are same like:

```
Select t1.name, t1.age as AgeFromT1, t2.age as AgeFromT2
from Table_1 t1
inner join Table_2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
```

Or you can use a subquery like:

```
Select table_1.*
from table_1
where name in (
                Select Table_2.name
                from Table_2
              )
```

Comment: I used the inner join, are there any benefits to subquery in this case?

Comment: inner join is better